# Can I simplify: $(¬P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q)$?

Tags: logic

I got stuck on this development:

$$\begin{align} (¬P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q) & \iff ((¬P ∧ Q) ∨ P) ∧ ((¬P ∧ Q) ∨ ¬Q) \tag{1} \\  
&\iff (P ∨ Q) ∧ (¬P ∨ ¬Q)   \tag{2}  \\
\end{align}$$

Can't this also be written as this using the associative and tautology Rules?

$$\begin{align} (¬P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ ¬Q) & \iff ((¬P ∧ Q) ∨ P) ∧ ((¬P ∧ Q) ∨ ¬Q) \tag{1'} \\  
&\iff (Q ∧ (¬P ∨ P)) ∧ (¬P ∧ (Q ∨ ¬Q))   \tag{2'}  \\
&\iff (Q ∧ ¬P)   \tag{2'}  \\
\end{align}$$
Is this correct?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi, I am just trying to see if I can simplify the original statement.

Comment: Your original statement just means that exactly one of $P$ and $Q$ is true.  You can write that in different ways, but none is much simpler than what you have.  Maybe the simplest is $\neg(P \leftrightarrow Q)$.  Or you may like $\neg\left((P \wedge Q) \vee (\neg P \wedge \neg Q)\right)$.

Comment: Hmm I don't understand, am I using the associativity and tautology rules incorrect?

Comment: Is that '=>' operator an implication or does it denote equivalence?

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Ok I understand, but then information was lost along the way... I didn't think using the rules would be "destructive"... Clearly something I have not understood :)

Comment: It was meant to imply equivalence, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Associativity applies when both operators are the same.  For a mixed expression like $p \vee (q \wedge r)$, you need distributivity instead.  Specifically, $p \vee (q \wedge r)$ is equivalent to $(p \vee q) \wedge (p \vee r)$.  Also, $p \wedge (q \vee r) \iff (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge r)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(\neg P\land Q)\lor(P\land\neg Q)$ is **not** equivalent to $Q\land \neg P$ -- for example when $Q$ is false and $P$ is true, the former is true and the latter is false.

---

It looks like you've been fooled into thinking that $(A\land B)\lor C$ is the same as $A\land(B\lor C)$. This is not the case. For example, when $C$ is true but $A$ and $B$ are false, $(A\land B)\lor C$ will be true but $A\land(B\lor C)$ will be false.

$\land$ is associative by itself, and $\lor$ is associative by itself, but they don't associate *with each other*.

Comment: No, $A\vee B$ does not imply $A$.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: No it doesn't. What was I thinking?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This misunderstanding of the associativity rule was clearly my mistake. Thank you for pointing that out. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The statement means: “$P$ or $Q$, the ‘or’ being exclusive,” or “exactly one of $P$ and $Q$.” This is the same as “$P$ or $Q$, but not both:” $$(P\vee Q)\wedge\lnot (P\wedge Q).$$

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can tell directly by looking at the form of the formula in question that it cannot be simplified in the way you're looking for: it is already "maximally simple" in the sense that it is in *disjunctive normal form*. A propositional formula with k variables $P_1, \ldots, P_k$ has a *unique* representation as a disjunction of 0 or more subformulas of the form $(\neg)^{\pm 1}P_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge (\neg)^{\pm 1}P_k$, where $(\neg)^{\pm 1}P$ can either be $P$ or $\neg P$.